# Is there a way to create a compile time type map in C++17 for type-checking?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, typechecking, typemaps

I'm a little new to C++ meta-programming/SFINAE, and I'm having trouble with developing a check to see if a type passed in to a method is contained within a predefined type-list. The context here is that I'd like to check against if the type that's being registered in my variant matches the output type in another structure. Each item that's registered in my application is mapped to another item (in a structure) via a tag (some number). I'd like to create a type-map that can be used at compile time to raise an assertion if the type that is to be registered doesn't match the type of the item in my wire protocol structure.

So something like:

```
// register elements in type map:
type_map::register(ID_1, decltype(wire_type_item_1)); 
type_map::register(ID_2, decltype(wire_type_item_2));
... etc.

// and when types are registered
template<typename T>
void add_item(const uint32_t id, const T item)
{
   // add static_assert here
   // look up type based on ID, and compare to type passed in
   // when add_item is called
   static_assert(std::is_same<type_map::find(id), decltype(T), 
                 "Attempted to register type that does not match wire type"); 

   ...
}
```

I'd appreciate any pointers on where to start/how to go about doing this - thanks!

Comment: It has a certain [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) smell about it. The types you use in your variant are type checked already. I don't understand what you really want to achieve.

Comment: `id` is a function parameter, so it can never be a compile-time constant. You could do something like `add_item<14>(type_with_id_14);`, would that work or could you try to be a bit more clear?

Comment: You’re correct - I made a typo in my original post. ID_1 and ID_2 are to be defined elsewhere as global constants accessible to this structure.

Comment: @KrishnaSoni Check `boost::hana`. It is designed to make your life easier for these kind of things. It requires some effort and time to learn it though.

Answer (score 5):

Following (and misunderstanding?) a suggestion in a comment from Yakk (thanks) at my first answer, I've written a really different (simpler and more elegant, IMHO) way to implement the compile time map.

First of all, the `ct_pair`. Now is more complex with a `using` type `type` (to get the template type `T` parameter) and a `static` function that, given the same index of the struct (wrapped in a `std::integral_constant`, to have different types from different implementation of `ct_pair`)

```
template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct ct_pair
 { 
   using type = T;

   static ct_pair get_pair (std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>)
    { return {}; }
 };
```

Now `std::tuple`, `std::tuple_cat()` and the helper class `get_tuple` aren't needed anymore and `ct_map` simply become

```
template <typename ... Ps>
struct ct_map : public Ps...
 {
   using Ps::get_pair...;

   template <std::size_t I>
   using find_type
      = typename decltype(get_pair(
            std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{}))::type;
 };
```

Now the full example (unfortunately C++17 and not before, when the other my answer should be C++11/C++14 compatible) become

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct ct_pair
 { 
   using type = T;

   static ct_pair get_pair (std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>)
    { return {}; }
 };

template <typename ... Ps>
struct ct_map : public Ps...
 {
   using Ps::get_pair...;

   template <std::size_t I>
   using find_type
      = typename decltype(get_pair(
            std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{}))::type;
 };

using type_map = ct_map<ct_pair<2u, char>,
                        ct_pair<3u, int>,
                        ct_pair<5u, long>,
                        ct_pair<7u, long long>>;

int main()
 {
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<type_map::find_type<5u>, long> );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach for creating a compile-time map between classes.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct foo {};
struct bar {};
struct ID_1 {};
struct ID_2 {};
struct ID_3 {};

template <class T>
struct type_map {};

template <>
struct type_map<ID_1> { using type = foo; }; // map ID_1 -> foo
template <>
struct type_map<ID_2> { using type = bar; }; // map ID_2 -> bar

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<type_map<ID_1>::type, foo>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<type_map<ID_2>::type, bar>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<type_map<ID_3>::type, int>); // fails, ID_3 isn't in map
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<type_map<ID_1>::type, bar>); // fails, ID_1 is mapped to foo, not bar
}
```

In your code sample, though, you have the following line: `static_assert(std::is_same<type_map::find(id), decltype(T), "Attempted to register type that does not match wire type");` The issue with this is that `id` is a runtime variable. You can't use `static_assert` at run-time.

If you do want to lookup types in this map at runtime, it's a bit more complicated. I would suggest using a metaprogramming library like `hana`, as it allows you to do things like loop through all elements of a compile-time data structure at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what do you exactly want... anyway...

Surely you can't use a `const std::uint32_t id` **value** to obtain (`find(id)`) a type (as a value of a function?) that you can use in a `static_assert()`

```
template <typename T>
void add_item (std::uint32_t const id, T const item)
// ................................^^  the value id is unusable in a static_assert()
```

If you know the value of `id` **compile** **time** (otherwise your question do not make sense) you can pass it (I suggest as `std::size_t`) as template value in a `std::integral_constant`

```
template <std::size_t ID, uintypename T>
void add_item (std::integral_constant<std::size_t, ID>, T const item)
```

or better, I suppose, directly as template parameter that you have to explicit calling `add_item()`.

Anyway... for the type map I propose, first of all, a `ct_pair` (compile time pair) between a `std::size_t` and a type

```
template <std::size_t, typename>
struct ct_pair
 { };
```

Given also a couple of helper structs as follows

```
template <std::size_t, std::size_t, typename>
struct get_tuple
 { using type = std::tuple<>; };

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct get_tuple<I, I, T>
 { using type = std::tuple<T>; };
```

you can create a `ct_map` (compile time map), using template specialization, the power of `std::tuple_cat()` together with `std::get_val()` and `decltype()` as follows

```
template <typename ...>
struct ct_map;

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct ct_map<ct_pair<Is, Ts>...>
 {
   template <std::size_t I>
   static constexpr auto find_type_func ()
    -> decltype( std::get<0>( std::tuple_cat(
             std::declval<typename get_tuple<I, Is, Ts>::type>()...)) );

   template <std::size_t I>
   using find_type
      = std::remove_reference_t<decltype( find_type_func<I>() )>;
 };
```

To register the elements on a map you have to define a `using`

```
using type_map = ct_map<ct_pair<2u, char>,
                        ct_pair<3u, int>,
                        ct_pair<5u, long>,
                        ct_pair<7u, long long>>;
```

and the `static_assert()` check become something as follows

```
static_assert( std::is_same_v<type_map::find_type<5u>, long> );
```

The following is a full compiling C++17 example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t, typename>
struct ct_pair
 { };

template <std::size_t, std::size_t, typename>
struct get_tuple
 { using type = std::tuple<>; };

template <std::size_t I, typename T>
struct get_tuple<I, I, T>
 { using type = std::tuple<T>; };

template <typename ...>
struct ct_map;

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct ct_map<ct_pair<Is, Ts>...>
 {
   template <std::size_t I>
   static constexpr auto find_type_func ()
    -> decltype( std::get<0>( std::tuple_cat(
             std::declval<typename get_tuple<I, Is, Ts>::type>()...)) );

   template <std::size_t I>
   using find_type
      = std::remove_reference_t<decltype( find_type_func<I>() )>;
 };

using type_map = ct_map<ct_pair<2u, char>,
                        ct_pair<3u, int>,
                        ct_pair<5u, long>,
                        ct_pair<7u, long long>>;

int main()
 {
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<type_map::find_type<5u>, long> );
 }
```

Comment: You can clean up your map using a trick: `template<std::size_t I, class T> pair<I,T> const& get( std::integral_constant<size_t, I>,  pair<I,T> const& rhs ){ return rhs; }`, then inherit from pair, and invoke `get( integral, foo )` -- the base class template deduction will find `T` for you.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - well... not sure to understand... but following your suggestion I've written a solution that is simpler and more elegant. A lot more elegant. But is completely different. Are you sure you don't want add it as a new answer yourself?

Comment: /shrug, I was just looking at the machinery you used for `find_type_func` and knew of another way.  You could go a little way with it, or further; the further solution removes the need for a central type-list registry.  I guess I could write it up...

Answer (score 0):

```
template<auto i>
using constant = std::integral_constant<decltype(i), i>;

template<class T>
struct tag_t {
  using type=T;
  // comparison with other tags!
  constexpr auto operator==( tag_t<T> ) const { return std::true_type{}; }
  constexpr auto operator!=( tag_t<T> ) const { return std::false_type{}; }
  template<class U>
  constexpr auto operator==( tag_t<U> ) const { return std::false_type{}; }
  template<class U>
  constexpr auto operator!=( tag_t<U> ) const { return std::true_type{}; }
};
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag = {};
```

Now we can work with integers and types as values.

```
type_map::register(ID_1, decltype(wire_type_item_1)); 
type_map::register(ID_2, decltype(wire_type_item_2));
... etc.
```

this becomes

```
auto wire_type_map( constant<ID_1> ) { return tag<wire_type_item_1>; }
auto wire_type_map( constant<ID_2> ) { return tag<wire_type_item_1>; }
```

this registration can be done in a distributed manner, so long as it is visible (from header files) at point of use.

```
// and when types are registered
template<typename T, uint32_t id>
void add_item(constant<id> id_tag, const T item)
{
   static_assert(wire_type_map( id_tag ) == tag<T>, 
             "Attempted to register type that does not match wire type"); 

   ...
}
```

this does require that the added item's integer value be a compile time constant at this point.

Often if you are reading the integer and the data off the wire, this isn't practical; there is no way to check **at compile time** that the integer you are reading matches a type.  But there is the ability to check **at compile time** that the integer you are providing matches the type.

OTOH, it might be easier to strip the integer argument entirely, and map the type to the integer, instead.